# r: sum values of previous observations

Tags: r, sum

I want to sum every two prior observations for each ID, and place them in a new column that is named 'prior_work'. May sound strange, but here is an example that should clarify what I'm trying to do. My data frame:

```
ID  Week  Hours
1   1     .00
1   2   24.00
1   3   25.00
1   4   22.00
1   5   19.00
1   6   20.00
2   1     .00
2   2     .00
2   3     .00
2   4     .00
2   5   16.00
2   6   16.00
```

What I need:

```
ID  Week  Hours  Hours_prior_two_weeks
1   1     .00    NA 
1   2   24.00    NA
1   3   25.00    24.00
1   4   22.00    49.00
1   5   19.00    47.00
1   6   20.00    41.00
2   1     .00    NA       #new ID / person here
2   2     .00    NA
2   3     .00      .00
2   4     .00      .00
2   5   16.00      .00
2   6   16.00    16.00
```

Tried basic aggregation and such, but I can't figure out how to sum 'prior observations'. Thanks!

Comment: This is called a "rolling sum" (or sometimes a "windowed sum"). If you search for that you'll find [plenty of examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+rolling+sum).

Comment: `c(NA, NA, zoo::rollsum(head(your_data$Hours, -1), k = 2))` might do the trick for a single group. You could use `dplyr` to do it by group, or use `data.table` which has its own `rollsum` function.

Comment: That works, but not for the separate ID's. I.e., I don't want the rollsum to use numbers that belong to different ID's in the first column.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't figure out how to use dplyr or data.table to split/recombine the file. My code seems to create a weird matrix. Any chance that you could help a little more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ave` function with `rollsum`, Need to change from the defaults for `fill` and `align` arguments to get the structure you requisitioned:

```
> dat$Hours_prior_two_weeks <- with(dat, ave( Hours, ID, FUN=function(x) rollsum(x, k=3, fill=NA, align="right")))
> dat
   ID Week Hours Hours_prior_two_weeks
1   1    1     0                    NA
2   1    2    24                    NA
3   1    3    25                    49
4   1    4    22                    71
5   1    5    19                    66
6   1    6    20                    61
7   2    1     0                    NA
8   2    2     0                    NA
9   2    3     0                     0
10  2    4     0                     0
11  2    5    16                    16
12  2    6    16                    32
```

But that didn't shift them so you need to add an extra NA at the beginning of the vectors within groups, as well as leaving one off the end (also within groups):

```
dat$Hours_prior_two_weeks <- with(dat, ave( Hours, ID, 
    FUN=function(x) c(NA, head(rollsum(x, k=2, fill=NA, align="right"), -1))) )
dat
#-----------
   ID Week Hours Hours_prior_two_weeks
1   1    1     0                    NA
2   1    2    24                    NA
3   1    3    25                    24
4   1    4    22                    49
5   1    5    19                    47
6   1    6    20                    41
7   2    1     0                    NA
8   2    2     0                    NA
9   2    3     0                     0
10  2    4     0                     0
11  2    5    16                     0
12  2    6    16                    16
```

Answer (score 4):

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(ID=rep(1:2, each=6), 
                Week=rep(1:6, each=2), 
                Hours=c(0,24,25,22,19,20,0,0,0,0,16,16))
df
#    ID Week Hours
# 1   1    1     0
# 2   1    1    24
# 3   1    2    25
# 4   1    2    22
# 5   1    3    19
# 6   1    3    20
# 7   2    4     0
# 8   2    4     0
# 9   2    5     0
# 10  2    5     0
# 11  2    6    16
# 12  2    6    16

df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Hours_Prior_Two_Weeks = lag(Hours, 2) + lag(Hours, 1))

# Source: local data frame [12 x 4]
# Groups: ID [2]
# 
#       ID  Week Hours Hours_Prior_Two_Weeks
#    (int) (int) (dbl)                 (dbl)
# 1      1     1     0                    NA
# 2      1     1    24                    NA
# 3      1     2    25                    24
# 4      1     2    22                    49
# 5      1     3    19                    47
# 6      1     3    20                    41
# 7      2     4     0                    NA
# 8      2     4     0                    NA
# 9      2     5     0                     0
# 10     2     5     0                     0
# 11     2     6    16                     0
# 12     2     6    16                    16
```

The above code uses `dplyr` to group by your `ID` variable and then uses `lag` to look back at the last two values.

Answer (score 3):

An option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,  Hours_prior_two_weeks := Reduce(`+`, shift(Hours, 1:2)), by = ID]
df1
#    ID Week Hours Hours_prior_two_weeks
# 1:  1    1     0                    NA
# 2:  1    2    24                    NA
# 3:  1    3    25                    24
# 4:  1    4    22                    49
# 5:  1    5    19                    47
# 6:  1    6    20                    41
# 7:  2    1     0                    NA
# 8:  2    2     0                    NA
# 9:  2    3     0                     0
#10:  2    4     0                     0
#11:  2    5    16                     0
#12:  2    6    16                    16
```